# Drupal Menu with Image

Tags: menu, drupal-6

I am working in Drupal 6.26 Project.I wanted to know,how to create the menu as in http://www.honda.com.my/ using drupal 6.26. which module is useful. I have used module named megamenu, but that module i cannot upload images and display those images with menu. How to display image with menu name along with readmore?

Answer (score 1):

As in one of my project I have same requirement and I use [Menu Icons](http://drupal.org/project/menu_icons) module.

> This module allows you to upload an image in the menu-item's configuration form.
>
> After uploading the image, the icon data will be added to the menu link's
>   options array.
>
> When a menu link is goes through the theme layer, it will receive an extra
>   class which by default is used to attach the images as a background image to the
>   corresponding menu item. These class names are also compatible with [Nice Menu's](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus).

Hope you will get what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have used menu_icons module in my project. But i didn't know how to display that icon at user interface. Please tell me how to display icon at user interface and not menu title.

Comment: Hey ! Sorry for late reply !
As you added image to that menu using this module you will get display  icon at user interface automatically . we do not have to do any thing . But ya , I think you miss Imagecache part. Please verify this thing also. It uses one of image cache property.
Hope it will work for you :)